# Symfony and Doctrine: project structure convention

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, autoload

I use symfony's ProjectConfiguration.class.php for configuring doctrine's connection:

```
public function configureDoctrineConnectionCertby(Doctrine_Connection $conn)
{
   $conn->setListener(new MyListner());
}
```

Where should I define MyListner class within a symfony project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a `lib/Doctrine` (or `lib/doctrine/Doctrine` - this is what Symfony does inside of sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) folder for all Doctrine files. Since Listeners are Doctrine files not Symfony files, you should be following *Doctrine* naming conventions for them. In this case, MyListener would go in:

`/lib/Doctrine/Record/Listener/MyListener.php`

This is the "proper" way to do this. It would of course work if you simply threw the files in `/lib` or `/lib/Doctrine`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your listener to be available at the project level, put it in the /project/lib/ folder.  If you just want it to be available at the module level, put it in the /project/apps/module/lib/ folder.

Comment: Does the name of the file matter? E.g. MyListner.php or MyListner.class.php Which autoloader loads this files? Symfony or Doctrine's?